# Remove group from the pandas dataframe when a specific value within the group occurs at least two times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
      'fruit': ['strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'strawberry', 'kiwi', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'banana', 'melon', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'melon']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    group   fruit
    A       strawberry
    A       strawberry
    A       strawberry
    A       strawberry
    A       strawberry
    B       kiwi
    B       banana
    B       strawberry
    B       orange
    B       kiwi
    C       banana
    C       melon
    C       orange
    C       kiwi
    C       melon
```

Using the code below i'm able to remove a `group` if that group contains any row with the `fruit` value 'strawberry'.

```
df[~df.fruit.eq('strawberry').groupby(df.group).transform('any')]

group   fruit
C       banana
C      melon
C       orange
C       kiwi
C       melon
```

However, I want to only remove a `group` if that group contains **at least two** rows with the `fruit value` 'strawberry', meaning that the end result should als include group B. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `transform('sum')`

```
n = 2
out = df[~(df.fruit.eq('strawberry').groupby(df.group).transform('sum')>=n)]

out
Out[108]: 
   group       fruit
5      B        kiwi
6      B      banana
7      B  strawberry
8      B      orange
9      B        kiwi
10     C      banana
11     C       melon
12     C      orange
13     C        kiwi
14     C       melon
```

Comment: That doesn't give the desired result unfortunately

Comment: Shouldn't you add a negation symbol after the first square bracket? If I understood it correctly, groups B and C should be returned in the output. In this case we see group A.

Comment: That's what I thought, but `df[~df.fruit.eq('strawberry').groupby(df.group).transform('sum')>=2]
` does not return the desired output of groups B and C

Comment: You should write it this way: `df[~(df.fruit.eq('strawberry').groupby(df.group).transform('sum')>=2)]`

Comment: @Arkadiusz check the update , and thx for your help ~

Comment: please add text breakdown describing what the code does