# Unclear why I'm getting a TypeError: str object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spark-koalas

I have a Koalas / Pandas-on-Spark dataframe named `df`.

When I try the function below I get a `TypeError: str object is not callable`

```
df[~(df.time.eq('00:00:00').groupby(df.vehicle_id).transform('sum')>=2)]
```

When I check the datatypes of both columns I get:

```
print(df.time.dtype)
<U0
print(df.vehicle_id.dtype)
<U0
```

Is that something that might have to deal with it?

Comment: Please provice a [mcve], including a small sample dataframe and the full traceback.

Comment: There's a function called `sum` -- are you sure you want `transform('sum')` and not `transform(sum)`?

Comment: @Samwise that should be fine, `transform` accepts a number of functions in string form, such as `'sum'`, `'mean'`, etc.

Comment: I used`transform('sum')` (with single quotes) on the same df but then as a pandas df without any problems before. Using `transform('sum')` on a Koalas df gives me a 
`TypeError: str object is not callable`. However, if I use `transform(sum)` (without single quotes) on a Koalas df, I get a different error: `TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types`. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you sum strings?

Comment: I sum the number of appearances grouped by `vehicle_id`. So if the value '00:00:00' in the `time` column appears more often than 2 times grouped per `vehicle_id`, i want to delete the whole group. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69991015/remove-group-from-the-pandas-dataframe-when-a-specific-value-within-the-group-oc)